options.TimestampFormat is deprecated. What is the alternative?
I've created a ILoggerFactory, and added a console provider. I want to add timestamp, but it sounds like options.TimestampFormat is obsolete.
        private static ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
    {
        builder.AddConsole(options =>
        {
            options.TimestampFormat = "HH:mm:ss ";
        });


What can I do instead? I can't find any solutions online.

"Use ConsoleFormatterOptions.Timestampformat instead" ?  Usually in Deprecated messages they suggest what replaced that feature? What exactly is your problem?

Well as someone not entirely fluent in C#, using ConsoleFormatterOptions instead of ConsoleLoggerOptions didn't provide much information for me. I did find the solution though.

I solved it myself. It was as simple as using builder.AddSimpleConsole() instead of builder.AddConsole().
